# Typography: Oldstyle vs. lining figures within running text to express statistical values

Tags: typography

I am just in the progress of setting my thesis. I usually use oldtyle figures within running text. However, I sometimes have to report statistical values. I am now unsure what is best practice here. Should I set all statistical values in lining figures (this improves readability – especially in the case where you want to use zeros; see example below) or should I stick with oldstyle numbers? Are there any kinds of rules concerning what figures should be set oldstyle and what figures as lining figures (e.g., non-statistical values should be set as oldstyle figures and all statistical values as lining figures)?

[image]

Comment: you could use `siunitx` to typeset statistical numbers using `\num{0.1}` and defining the font used by `siunitx` to use lining figures.

Comment: This is not really a TeX question, is it?  As a matter of style your first one might be better as ... close to zero represents ... which would avoid the problem, and in the second using an explicit math formula such as `$\beta>0.1$`  might be better.

Comment: I do know this question is rather OT. However, I decided to post it here because the tag `typography` existed. I also know that this is a matter of style, a normative question---to put it differently. However, I am unsure hwo to set my figures. That is why I asked.